# mobile web app HTML and JavaScript file location

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile, mobile-application

I'm new to mobile web app development. I have a simple fundamental question regarding mobile web app. Mobile web app is written in HTML and JavaScript. So are these HTML and JavaScript files stored on the mobile device locally or sent from a server? This question may be too simple for most people. But I ask this because if all JavaScript code is stored on mobile device, then how about cross domain access issues? Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify cross domain access issues? Thanks

Comment: I mean if JS file is located on the mobile device, then due to same origin policy, it cannot make ajax request to access resource on the server unless server allows so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you package it in [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) you will have all your assets stored in a single package that can be installed in multiple devices, but if you're working on a mobile web app thats served from a remote server, all the scripts, templates and css's will have to be downloaded. If you're having issues with cross domain comunications, try using [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in your requests.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using PhoneGap. So my JS files should be packed and installed on mobile devices. For cross domain access, if the server doesn't support JSONP, then how do I do it?

Comment: I think you only can make crossdomain requests using JSONP. [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is another option, but sadly it's not ready yet and also depends on the server technology.

Answer (score 0):

All the files are downloaded each time you request certain url, for mobile devices and pcs as well.(the file will be downloaded or not depending on the caching setting, if the file was modified, etc)